# Return dataframe modified by function in R

Tags: r, function

I made a function which is searching for outliners in each row of dataframe. What i'd like to get at the end is modified dataframe with new column `x$outliers_numb` as return not as just `print`. I added `return()` function at the end but it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

```
outliers <- function(x, s, e){
  
  # x = dataframe
  # s = index of first col to take
  # e = index of last column to take
  
  p <- x
  
  for(i in s:e){
    
    Q1 <- quantile(p[,i], 0.25, names = FALSE)
    Q3 <- quantile(p[,i], 0.75, names = FALSE)
    iqr <- IQR(p[,i])
    low <- Q1 - iqr*1.5
    up <- Q3 + iqr*1.5
    
    p[,i] <- ((p[,i] < low) | (p[,i] > up))
  }
  
  p <- p %>% mutate(outliers_numb = rowSums(p[,s:e]))
  x$outliers_numb <- p$outliers_numb
  
  return(x)
}


#example
w <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 90, 6),
                col2 = c(13, 60, 13, 18, 13, 12, 0),
                col3 = c(1, 899, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6))

outliers(w, 1, 3)
```

Comment: What part of that is not giving you what you want? When I run your code I see a data frame with a `outliers_numb` column. If you want to use it later, assign it to a variable (`new_var <- outliers(w, 1, 3)`).

Comment: `return(x$outliers_numb)` only prints out in console. I wonder if I could return `outliers_numb` or `x` with new column as dataframe in my environment so after using `outliers()` function I have dataframe with new column and I can manipulate with it

Comment: cazman, ok, actually you're right. I feel so stupid now. Thank you :D

Comment: Just assign `outliers(...)` to some variable. That variable will be a data frame with the new column. It is printing the data frame because you have not assigned the return result to anything. You could use the super assignment operator `<<-` to assign the result to something in the parent scope, but I would not recommend this because it is not re-usable, and because [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) can cause a variety of problems and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it to a new variable

```
dataframe_to_reus <- outliers(w, 1, 3)
```